# how do i update my database before a user leaves a certain aspx site

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf

I am currently trying to update by database through  AJAX enabled WCF however i cannot seem to trigger the contracted function in the service. Does anyone have an idea?. I have already placed the script manager and the reference to the server and i have already applied the same theory within the same page and the other functions work perfectly however this one does not seem to work.

Here is my code

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {

        alert("alerting server");
        var service = new ServiceNameSpace.Service();
        service.Function(document.getElementById("info2").value, 
                         document.getElementById("Info1").value, Recieves, 
                         FailsRecievesLogout, null);
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public void DoWork(string info2, string info1)
    {
        //code
    }
```

Markup:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ServiceName.svc" />
        </Services>
 </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: No just plain ASP.net aspx

Comment: I will bump your question but without more detailed information around the problem it's hard to say what is going on. Have you tried comparing  the differences with what works and what does not?